# Passing files in different S3 folders as input to mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce

Our log files are stored in year/month/day/hourly buckets on S3. See below for structure.

How do i pass all the logs on day=20 as input to my map reduce program?

Eg:

bucket  = logs/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=1/log1_1.txt

bucket  = logs/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=2/log2_1.txt

bucket  = logs/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=2/log2_2.txt

bucket  = logs/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=2/log2_3.txt

bucket  = logs/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=3/log3_1.txt

bucket  = logs/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=4/log4_1.txt

Comment: Please follow the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501276/best-practice-to-pass-copy-of-object-to-all-mappers-in-hadoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "bucket" do you actually mean distinct S3 buckets or do you mean folders/directories in a bucket? Creating that many buckets will end up hitting the S3 account limit for the number of buckets you can create.

Assuming you meant folders/directories in the bucket, use [s3distcp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) as a step in your EMR cluster to copy the logs you want to HDFS and then use the HDFS directory as the input to the MR program

s3distcp takes an src directory and a srcPattern to filter the items found in src. In your example, you could do:

```
./elastic-mapreduce --jobflow JobFlowID --jar \
/home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar \
--arg --src --arg s3://logs/ \
--arg --srcPattern --arg '.*day-20.*'
--arg --dest --arg hdfs://input/
```

All of the logs files that have day=20 in the path will be copied to the input directory on the HDFS of the EMR cluster with JobFlowID.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Parrinello. You are right, i meant folders.